# why are we getting a Identifier not found '_row_id' in Cognos 11

Tags: cognos-11

XQE-V5-0005 Identifier not found '_row_id'. CAF-WRN-2082 An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator. The complete error has been logged by CAF with SecureErrorID:2023-08-07-14:40:30.341-#33

User is getting the above error and can't run a report built on a data module.  However, as an administrator, I can run the report.  When I googled the error, IBM says its due to either the data module or uploaded file are loaded in My Content, not Team Content.  This is not the case.  Both are loaded into a Team Content folder which is restricted to administrators.

I tested all of the queries in the report, but it runs fine for the administrator.

Comment: A user or all users who are not administrators or some users?

Comment: My hypothesis is that, because the data module is denied to {some set of your users} through it being in the folder which is denied to {some set of your users} the metadata of the data module necessarily is denied to them, which would explain the error.  If that is the case then it would be nice if the error message was clearer about what is going on.

Comment: Any update on this?  Can you confirm my questions please.

Comment: We figured out the issue.  The data module was pulling an uploaded spreadsheet from My Content instead of Team Content.  So, the report was working fine for the administrators but not for the users.  Thanks for your input.